# How to install the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe"?

Tags: c++, node.js, windows-10

I tried to install VCBuilder.exe.

```
$npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

But it doesn't work well.

An Error is like this:

```
> windows-build-tools@1.2.1 postinstall C:\Users\Josephine\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools
> node ./lib/index.js

Downloading BuildTools_Full.exe
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND download.microsoft.com download.microsoft.com:443
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND download.microsoft.com download.microsoft.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:73:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'download.microsoft.com',
  host: 'download.microsoft.com',
  port: 443 }
```

I don't understand this error.
please, help me.

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that it's trying to locate some resource on Microsoft's download site that is no longer where it used to be (HTTP 404). Microsoft keeps moving around things all the time. Perhaps you get more hints if you run `npm` in verbose mode?

Comment: what is verbose mode? I can't understand well.

Comment: ***what is verbose mode?*** A mode that provides more descriptive messages.. add `--verbose` to your command line. https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config

Comment: It is a failed DNS lookup for "download.microsoft.com".  It is still there, honest.  You need a better Internet.

Answer (score 0):

use this version to install it

> npm install --global --production windows-build-tools@4.0.0